# Получение строки

Tags: java

```
public class Context {  
    String first="";  
    String second="";  
    String finalResult;  
    String operation;

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        if (operation == null) {
            first += Integer.toString(number);
           setDisplay(first);
        } else if (first != null && operation != null ){
            second += Integer.toString(number);
           setDisplay(second);
        }

    }

    public void setOperation(String operation) {

        if (operation.equals("=")) {
            calculate();
        }
         this.operation = operation;
    }

    public void calculate() {
        int firstInt = Integer.parseInt(first);
        int secondInt = Integer.parseInt(second);
        int resultInt = 0;

        if (operation.equals("+")) {
           resultInt += firstInt+secondInt;
            }
        setDisplay(Integer.toString(resultInt));
    }

    public void setDisplay(String s ){
         finalResult  = s;
    }

}
```

Почему finalResult = null ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalResult  устанавливается только в setDisplay. Следовательно если вы не вызвали метод setDisplay или установили null в качестве аргумента метода - то вы и получаете ваш null

Comment: setDisplay() я вызываю в методах выше и они передают нужны параметр в String s